# Change text in Product Attachement Grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, product-grid

How to change text in Product grid if any product not found. I have attached this in custom module and now want to change text according to my need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your module you need create

> Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\adminhtml_integration_grid_block.xml

And put this inside

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="integration.grid.columnSet">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="empty_text" xsi:type="string">Your text</argument>
        </arguments>
      </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: its not working.

Comment: changed block name. try now

Comment: i have created this grid in form using Ui component, where i would add this lines?

Comment: In ui components you cann`t set this
You need create this layout

Comment: look here http://i.imgur.com/dgVMBvm.png this is how i created my form and then this is how i attachd the grid http://i.imgur.com/8TjfZPc.png